# Finding/editing all matches in nested json?

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I have a json that goes something like this,

```
[
  {
    team: 'Hello',
    members: ['John', 'Paul'],
    points: 0;
  },
  {
    team: 'Bye',
    members: ['John', 'Mary'],
    points: 0;
  }
]
```

How do I go about searching all teams to find any that has a member called 'John' and add 10 points to each team that matches?

Actually it's a Mongo collection and I'm using `var teams = Teams.find().fetch()` to turn it into json, should I not even do that and try to do the matching on collection level so that I can edit it?

Comment: this is a fairly basic mongo question with tons of help online. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried loop within loops to find the right team members already, but now I'm having issues trying to update it.
`Teams.update(myTeam, {$inc: {'members.o.1': Number(score)}});`
Where o should be a dynamic number added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the update operation on the server you can use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to find documents where the specified value matches an array element.

**Server:**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Teams.update({
        "members": {
            $in: ["John"]
        }
    }, {
        $inc: {
            points: 10
        }
    }, {
        multi: true
    });
}
```

If you want to run this on the client, you can only update documents by using the `_id` field, otherwise you will receive this error:

> Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.
>   [403]

As a consequence, you need to run the [`cursor.forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method and subsequently update all matching documents.

**Client:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Teams.find({
        "members": {
            $in: ["John"]
        }
    }).forEach(function(doc) {
        Teams.update({
            _id: doc._id
        }, {
            $inc: {
                points: 10
            }
        });
    });
}
```